# How to keep panel scroll on top when dynamically adding controls to it?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I am adding user controls to a panel that is empty, but when i do that, the scroll of the panel goes down.

I tried to set the `panel.verticalscrol.value` to 0 but that does not do the trick.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your own panel:

```
Public Class PanelEx
  Inherits Panel

  Protected Overrides Function ScrollToControl(activeControl As Control) As Point
    Return Me.DisplayRectangle.Location
  End Function

End Class
```

This will prevent your usercontrol (which probably has a textbox or something focusable in it) from moving the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2):

Use `panel.ScrollControlIntoView(<first dynamically created control>)`.